# String.getBytes() returns array of Unicode chars

Tags: java, arrays, unicode

I was reading getbytes and from documentation it states that it will return 
     **the resultant byte array**.

But when i ran the following program, i found that it is returning array of Unicode symbols.

```
public class GetBytesExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = new String("A");
        byte[] array1 = str.getBytes();
        System.out.print("Default Charset encoding:");
        for (byte b : array1) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }

    }
}
```

The above program prints output

```
Default Charset encoding:65
```

This `65` is equivalent to Unicode representation of `A`. My question is that where are the bytes whose return type is expected.

Comment: What do you expect this method to return? You just printed each byte of the returned array, so they are definitely there. What is your expectation?

Comment: *"My question where are the bytes that the return type is taking about."* In your variable `b`? Quite unclear what your issue with this code is.

Comment: "where are the bytes" Well... in the array. You are simply misinterpreting what is happening when you print the elements of that array.

Comment: @AndyTurner-- thanks a lot i understand it now by the concept of widening..:)

Comment: Even if there was no widening, what would you expect to be printed? A byte is a signed integer number on 8 bits (so from -128 to 127). 65 looks like a valid byte value to me.

Comment: A is used for example here only..i tried a whole string initially which gives me result that does not fit into byte data...so i raised the concern

Comment: My guess is that you were confused by the fact that you use print(), so all bytes are concatenated, without any space of new line between each of them.

Comment: Using the default character set and encoding fills a very specialized need that rarely applies anymore. If you want to explore character sets and encodings, just use specific ones because the rule of character encodings is: Read with exactly the one that was used for writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `PrintStream.print(byte)` overload, so the `byte` needs to be widened to invoke the method.

Per [JLS 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - ...

There's no `PrintStream.print(short)` overload either.

The next most-specific one is `PrintStream.print(int)`. So that's the one that's invoked, hence you are seeing the numeric value of the byte.

Answer (score 1):

`String.getBytes()` returns the encoding of the string using the platform encoding. The result depends on which machine you run this. If the platform encoding is UTF-8, or ASCII, or ISO-8859-1, or a few others, an 'A' will be encoded as 65 (aka 0x41).

Answer (score 1):

> This 65 is equivalent to Unicode representation of A

It is *also* equivalent to a UTF-8 representation of A

It is *also* equivalent to a ASCII representation of A

It is *also* equivalent to a ISO/IEC 8859-1 representation of A

It so happens that the encoding for A is similar in a lot character encodings, and that these are all similar to the Unicode code-point.  And this is not a coincidence.  It is a result of the history of character set / character encoding standards.

---

> My question is that where are the bytes whose return type is expected.

In the byte array, of course :-)

You are (just) misinterpreting them.

When you do this:

```
    for (byte b : array1) {
        System.out.print(b);
    }
```

you output a series of bytes as decimal numbers with no spaces between them.  This is consistent with the way that Java distinguishes between text / character data and binary data.  Bytes are binary.  The `getBytes()` method gives a binary encoding (in some character set) of the text in the string.  You are then formatting and printing the binary (one byte at a time) as decimal numbers.

If you want more evidence of this, replace the `"A"` literal with a literal containing (say) some Chinese characters.  Or any Unicode characters greater than `\u00ff` ... expressed using `\u` syntax.